# C++: expected identifier before numeric constant

Tags: c++, matrix

I'm trying to write a small program using MTL, but I'm getting the mentioned error when I try to make a MTL Matrix a member of a class.

```
#include <boost/numeric/mtl/mtl.hpp>

class myClass
{
private:
    mtl::dense2D<double> Ke(6,6);
};
```

However, there is no problem with the same statement in main():

```
#include <boost/numeric/mtl/mtl.hpp>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    mtl::dense2D<double> Ke(6,6);
    return 0;    
}
```

I'm very new to C++, and I don't think this is really related to the MTL, but that's where the error occurred for me.

Comment: Is MTL still supported by Boost?  I couldn't find it on the web site, and there was only historic hits in a forum about it.

Comment: I dont' think it is. But it is using Boost extensively, I think. Also, the creator may hope it becomes accepted for Boost one day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do that in the constructor's initialiser list.

```
class myClass {
    mtl::dense2D<double> Ke;
public:
    myClass() : Ke(mtl::dense2D<double>(6, 6)) { }
};
```

Comment: Heh, good find. I somehow just saw the missing `using namespace boost;` or `boost::`. :P

Comment: Isn't myClass() : Ke(6, 6) { } enough ?

Answer (score 4):

Because when you declare

```
mtl::dense2D<double> Ke;
```

you're only supposed to **declare** it, not create it yet. This is the constructor's job in C++:

```
class myClass
{
public:
    myClass() // constructor
        : Ke(6, 6) // here we use the constructor initializer
    {
    }
private:
    mtl::dense2D<double> Ke; // declaration
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure, that this will compile :)

Comment: @Kiril: Reason being? I don't see anything wrong with this code.

Comment: Doh! Sorry, my bad. That's why I said "not sure" not "will not compile" :D

Answer (score 3):

You can't initialize variable within the class scope, you need to do it in a constructor.  Change this:

```
class myClass
{
private:
    mtl::dense2D<double> Ke(6,6);
};
```

to this --

```
class myClass
{
public:
    myClass() : Ke(6,6) { }
private:
    mtl::dense2D<double> Ke;
};
```